# How can I show the number of file type depending upon the data in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am displaying the dynamic input file type field. There is no issue with creating dynamic file type and inserting the data into the database.

I have inserted the data like `a.png,b.png,c.png,d.png` and I can fetch the data from the database.

Now my issue is, I am on edit page and how can I show the number of file type depending upon the data? I mean if the user uploaded 2 images then show 2 file type if 3 then show 3 file type.

I know I can do this using `explode` method but The User is on edit page so he/she can add the more file type.

**Below code is the UI code.**

```js
$(function() {

  const max_fields = 5;
  const $wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap .row");
  const $add_button = $(".add_field_button");
  const template = '<div class="col-lg-4 mb-3"><div class="customfileWrap"><div class=" upload_file"><input type="file" name="slider[]" class="fileupload"><span class="excel_upload_icon"></span><p id="file-name"></p><span class="upload_text"> Click here to upload file </span><div class="gallery"></div></div><a href="#" class="remove_field"> <i class="fas fa-times"></i> </a></div></div>';

  let fileUploadCount = 1;

  $add_button.click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (fileUploadCount < max_fields) {
      fileUploadCount++;
      $wrapper.append(template);
    }
  });

  $wrapper.on('click', '.remove_field', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //$(this).closest('.customfileWrap').remove();
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
    fileUploadCount--;
  })

  $wrapper.on('change', '.fileupload', function() {
    imagesPreview(this);

  });

  // Multiple images preview in browser
  const imagesPreview = function(input) {
    const placeToInsertImagePreview = $(input).parent().find('div.gallery');

    if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;

      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {
          $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.upload_file {
  border: 3px dashed #042954;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  height: 120px;
}

.upload_file input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove_field {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.upload_file img {
  width: 100px;
}

.customfileWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.remove_field {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="innerWrpperpadding bg-white">
      <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button mb-3">Add More Images</button>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="customfileWrap">
              <div class=" upload_file">
                <input type="file" name="slider[]" id="fileupload1" class="fileupload">
                <span class="excel_upload_icon"></span>
                <p id="file-name"></p>
                <span class="upload_text"> Click here to upload file </span>
                <div class="gallery"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried this logic and I am getting my output with little bit issue. The user can add only 5 file type but here i can add 5 file type along with number of explode data.

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="innerWrpperpadding bg-white">
      <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button mb-3">Add More Images</button>
        <div class="row">
           <?php $sliders=explode(",", $companyInfo['slider']);
                 foreach ($sliders as $key => $h) {?>
          <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3">
            <div class="customfileWrap">
              <div class=" upload_file">
                <input type="file" name="slider[]" id="fileupload1" class="fileupload">
                <span class="excel_upload_icon"></span>
                <p id="file-name"></p>
                <span class="upload_text"> Click here to upload file </span>
                <div class="gallery"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: explode is enough, every time you try to update data, you have new fileTypes from client. maybe i didn't understand correctly

Comment: @ArashYounesi, For example, explode count is 3 then I will get the 3 file type and The user can add only 2 more file types if needed.

Comment: So you mean how to get that 3 number in your js/jquery code ?

Comment: Instead of `let fileUploadCount = 1;` use `let fileUploadCount = $(".fileupload").length`

Comment: @Swati, I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).length is not a function

Comment: I think I have to use let fileUploadCount = $(".fileupload").length

Comment: yes without  `()` see if that works .

Comment: @Swati, Yes, it's working. Thank you :)